# Adding buttons via code behind using XamlReader.Parse Causes exception

Tags: c#, xaml, exception

I am writing a program that reads in a group of files. Inside of these files is a line of XAML to add a button. I don't know anything about the button setup other than it is properly formed XAML.

When I use XamlRead.Parse it throws the exception" : Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'Cannot create unknown type 'Button'.' Line number '1' and line position '2'.

For testing my input file looks like so:

```
<Button Width="250" Height="50" Content="Button From Test File" Background="Yellow"/>
```

And my code looks like:

```
... 
    int start = filedata.IndexOf("<Button");
    if (start >=0)
    {
        string btnData = filedata.Substring(start, filedata.IndexOf("/>") - start + 2);                    

        Button cmdButton = CreateButton(btnData);
    }
...

private Button CreateButton(string ButtonXML)
{
     Button newButn = new Button();

     newButn = (Button)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(ButtonXML);

     return NewButn;
}
```

When I put the Button XAML into my mainwindow.xaml project file it shows the button fine.

Why is it giving me the exception?

Comment: I think your missing the xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" tag from the button.  When you define it in code i bet that tag is in the window declaration at the top of the xaml file, which is then inherited by all the controls defined in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Hack was able to point me in the right direction. I wanted to keep the code in the input files clean so I decided to do a little twiddling with the string when it was passed in. The create button function now looks like so:

```
private Button CreateButton(string ButtonXML)
{
    Button newButn = new Button();
    ButtonXML = ButtonXML.Replace("<Button", @"<Button xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' ");

    newButn = (Button)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(ButtonXML);

    return NewButn;
}
```